# how to choose between two lines number in linux command line

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have a large file containing 400K rows.

I have to select rows between 45,000 to 50,000.

I know I can write a have program and keep counting the rows and then select the lines between the interval.

However, would love to know is there a way from doing in command line in the shell?

Comment: Both sed and awk have simple commands to pick a range of lines. `awk 'NR > 50000 { exit } NR >= 45000' does it, and avoids reading the last 350000 records too.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk '
    NR>=45000 && NR<=50000
    NR>50000{exit}
' file
```

You can even pass variables to awk:

```
awk -v min=45000 -v max=50000 '
    NR >= min && NR <= max
    NR >  max{exit}
' file
```

Comment: You can avoid reading the last 350,000 rows with an exit.

Comment: Should be fixed now